# List of english words about particular topics

Tags: file, text

I'm looking for a list of english words that are associated with or related to the topic of technology. I would also like to find a list such as this for politics and weather.

So far I have only found a complete list of english words: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

However, I'm only interested in using the words about technology, politics, and weather.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined by the [help]. Try asking on http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TylerH I seriously doubt this will be appreciated on English.SE. I can't see a list of words request going over well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate They actually receive lots of word requests over on English.SE; it's a fairly popular tag. Looking closer at this question, though, it looks like he is trying to find a selection of words from an existing list, so really this should be closed as unclear instead, since it doesn't seem to be a programmatic attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I ended up finding lists here: https://github.com/imsky/wordlists

This should work.